# What is this propeller found underwater in the English Channel?

Tags: aviation-history, propeller, aircraft-identification

[image]

I need some help identifying this piece.

Comment: It would help if you gave some measurements, identifying numbers, etc. From the picture it is a twisted-up 3 blade prop which were pretty common. Whoever was at the other end of that thing probably had a really bad day.

Comment: Given the rust on the hub, I really really doubt any numbers or text will be legible. You probably won't even see where the text used to be...

Comment: looks like a smallish variable pitch, constant speed, metal propeller that's been in the water for not all that long (or has had a lot of corrosion cleaned away already).

Comment: Based on the fact that the blades remain mostly straight, it was probably not under power when it hit the water.

Comment: The asker never came back to give clarifying information such as size, so I'm voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that propeller is related to the 19 **June 1954 – Swissair Convair CV-240** flight which was ditched in the English Channel near Folkestone due to fuel exhaustion. As @AEhere mentioned earlier it looks like the propeller wasn't under power.
[image]the propeller shape look similar **but still the size of the propeller being provided in the photo relatively small compared to the actual aircraft propeller.**

Sources :

Wikipedia:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_accidents_and_incidents_involving_airliners_in_the_United_Kingdom

http://www.sr692.com/fleet/15_cv240/index.html

Comment: The square tips on the Convair propeller look quite different to the one round tip on the prop in the photo.

Comment: @PeterKämpf I‘d add sizes don’t seem right, either